# Postgresql INSERT ON CONFLICT syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

Greetings with the following test table:

```
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE pid start 10000;
SELECT nextval ('pid');

CREATE TEMP TABLE project_test (
  id int DEFAULT nextval('pid') primary key,
  project_id int UNIQUE NOT NULL
    );
```

I am attempting to make a statement that either inserts a new value for project_id returning the id or returns the id if the project_id exists.

I have attempted the following:

```
INSERT INTO project_test(project_id) VALUES(50) RETURNING id 
ON CONFLICT (project_id) DO UPDATE project_test SET project_id = 50 WHERE project_id = 50 RETURNING id;
```

I have read the documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html
I am on Postgres 13

I am getting a syntax error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"

Thanks in advance for any tips

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO project_test(project_id) VALUES(50)
ON CONFLICT (project_id) DO UPDATE SET project_id = 50 WHERE project_test.project_id = 50 RETURNING id;
```

The problem was the RETURNING id needs to go at the end, and then it thought column reference "project_id" was ambiguous, which is odd.
Thanks all

Comment: It is not odd - you have to disambiguate between the conflicting row in the table and the row you wanted to insert (accessible through the alias `EXCLUDED`).